# How do I make multiple multi-item substitution based on index in python lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, replace

Suppose I have a python list which looks like this:

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And a list of tuples with replacing instructions in the format (starting index, ending index, elements to replace with)

```py
b = [ (2,5,["x","y"])  , (8,8,["z"]) ]
```

How do I make the substitution without messing with the indices? I've tried but can't get the right approach.

Expected output:

```py
c = [0, 1, "x", "y", 6, 7, "z", 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
deleted = 0
for start, end, replacement in b:
    a[start - deleted:end + 1 - deleted] = replacement
    deleted += (end + 1 - start) - len(replacement)
```